# Retrieving Geolocation fields from a Lightning web component using getRecord()

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-data-service

I am attempting to retrieve the value of a Geolocation field in a Lightning web component by using wire service with the uiRecordApi's getRecord() method.

I can import the compound field or its individual pieces.

```
import FIELD_Location from '@salesforce/schema/Photo__c.Location__c';
import FIELD_Latitude from '@salesforce/schema/Photo__c.Location__Latitude__s';
import FIELD_Longitude from '@salesforce/schema/Photo__c.Location__Longitude__s';
```

However when I attempt the call to getRecord() it fails

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$id', fields: [FIELD_Name, FIELD_Latitude, FIELD_Longitude]})
wiredPhoto;
```

It populates wiredPhoto.error with a message that Location__c does not exist.

I worked around this by creating formula fields to hold latitude and longitude and I can read those using getRecord() without an issue, but that seems subpar.

Has anyone else run into the same issue? Wondering if I'm missing something obvious or if this is a known limitation.

---

EDIT: The requirement for not using @salesforce/schema is now [documented in the LWC docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about)

> NOTE You can’t import geolocation fields from @salesforce/schema.
>   Instead, to access a geolocation field or its constituent fields, use
>   string syntax.

```
// User.Place_of_birth__c is a compound custom field of type Geolocation
const PLACE_OF_BIRTH_LAT_FIELD = 'User.Place_of_birth__Latitude__s';
const PLACE_OF_BIRTH_LON_FIELD = 'User.Place_of_birth__Longitude__s';
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**added based on comments**

It seems there is a bug for importing geolocation fields (able to import other compound fields like BillingCity). So, we can use direct string notation as below.

---

`Geolocation` type fields are [Compound Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_geolocate_overview.htm&type=5) (like `BillingAddress`). Two main points to be highlighted from docs is :

> Geolocation is a compound field that counts toward your org’s limits
>   as three custom fields: one for latitude, one for longitude, and one
>   for internal use. Support for the compound field (geolocation) versus
>   the field’s components (latitude and longitude) varies depending on
>   the functionality you’re using in Salesforce. For example, you can
>   create list views that show the field and its components, but you
>   can’t select the compound geolocation field in Apex. You can run SOQL
>   queries only on a geolocation field’s components.
>
> Compound fields are accessible only through the SOAP and REST APIs.
>   The compound versions of fields aren’t accessible anywhere in the
>   Salesforce user interface.

Below is the working sample code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$recordId',
        fields: [ 'Account.Acc_Location__Latitude__s', 'Account.Acc_Location__Longitude__s' ]
    })
    wiredAcc({ data, error }) {
        console.log('Account => ', JSON.stringify(data), JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

and its output:

```
{
  "apiName": "Account",
  "childRelationships": {

  },
  "fields": {
    "Acc_Location__Latitude__s": {
      "displayValue": null,
      "value": 1.2345678
    },
    "Acc_Location__Longitude__s": {
      "displayValue": null,
      "value": 2.3456789
    }
  },
  "id": "00128000009j45sAAA",
  "lastModifiedById": "00528000001IIBvAAO",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2019-08-25T14:37:49.000Z",
  "recordTypeInfo": null,
  "systemModstamp": "2019-08-25T14:37:49.000Z"
}
```

Note that you should ideally use imported fields instead of direct strings in parameter

Comment: I have accepted your answer as you have provided an excellent bit of new information - that querying the __s fields by name rather than importing them does work and eliminates the need for formula fields.

Comment: However, I wanted to also ask if you ran into the same error I did when trying to import the __s fields ... I am unable to query the imported latitude__s and longitude__s  fields, have you had any luck? I am excluding the compound field from the query.

Comment: Am also getting error - modified answer.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: This is now documented in the LWC docs and I've added an update to the question reflecting that.

Answer (score 0):

The imports can be replaced as shown below:

```
import FIELD_Latitude from '@salesforce/schema/Photo__c.Location__Latitude__s';
import FIELD_Longitude from '@salesforce/schema/Photo__c.Location__Longitude__s';

/** My code goes here*/
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
const FIELD_Latitude ='Photo__c.Geolocation__Latitude__s';
const FIELD_Longitude ='Photo__c.Geolocation__Longitude__s';
const PHOTO_FIELDS = [FIELD_Latitude,FIELD_Longitude];
```